# direct execution of python scripts

Tags: shell-script, python, executable, exec

I have noticed that sometimes python scripts are not being started directly, ie `/foo/bar.py`, but rather from a shell script, which does nothing else than `/usr/bin/python -O /foo/bar.py $@`

One such example is `wicd` network manager. `/usr/bin/wicd-gtk` is a shell script, which starts the `wicd-client.py`:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/wicd-gtk

exec /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py $@
```

What is the purpose of this extra step?

What would be the difference if I started `/usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py` directly (provided it is executable) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the full script — the script does other things before running `wicd-client.py`. It first ensures that a certain directory and a certain symbolic link exist:

> ```
> # check_firstrun()
> if [ ! -d "$HOME/.wicd" ]; then
>     mkdir -p "$HOME/.wicd"
> fi
> # Make sure the user knows WHEREAREMYFILES ;-)
> if [ -e "/var/lib/wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" ] && [ ! -L "$HOME/.wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" ]; then
>     ln -s "/var/lib/wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" "$HOME/.wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES"
> fi
> ```

Then it runs Python with the `-O` option, which causes it to optimize the bytecode. I don't know how useful that is.

The wrapper script also forces `/usr/bin/python` to be used, whereas `/usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, so it picks up whichever `python` comes first in the command search path. On most systems this won't make any difference.

Note that there's a bug in this script: `$@` should be `"$@"`. The wrapper script will fail if any argument contains whitespace or wildcard characters `\[*?`.

You could safely run `/usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py` manually, as long as `~/.wicd` exists. The Debian package doesn't make it executable, though; maybe other distributions do.

Answer (score 3):

(Pure speculation follows.)

What you have is a packaged version of Wicd, and the package maintainers have tested it with the version of Python packaged by the distribution. However, `/usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py` is written with this shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It may well be the case that `/usr/bin/env` picks up a different `python` than `/usr/bin/python`, especially if you do any Python programming. The packager might have wanted to avoid that, if only to decrease the chances of issues popping up due to Wicd being run under a different Python version, or the libraries being used of a different version.

And they might have wanted to do other preparatory tasks. `wicd-gtk` on Ubuntu 14.04 has this `/usr/bin/wicd-gtk`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# check_firstrun()
if [ ! -d "$HOME/.wicd" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$HOME/.wicd"
fi
# Make sure the user knows WHEREAREMYFILES ;-)
if [ -e "/var/lib/wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" ] && [ ! -L "$HOME/.wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" ]; then
    ln -s "/var/lib/wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES" "$HOME/.wicd/WHEREAREMYFILES"
fi

exec /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py $@
```